# Python: How to find all matches in a multiline string but not proceeded by particular word?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have SQL codes and I would like to extract the table name after the "insert" keyword.

Basically, I would like to extract using the following rules:

1. Contains the word "insert"
2. Followed by the word "into" which is optional
3. Exclude if the there's a "--" (which is single line comment in SQL) anywhere before the insert into(optional) keyword.
4. Exclude if insert into(optional) keyword is between "/*" and "*/" (which is multiline comment in SQL).
5. Get the next word (table_name) after insert into (optional) keyword

Example:

```
import re

lines = """begin insert into table_1 end
    begin insert table_2 end   
    select 1 --This is will not insert into table_3
    begin insert into
        table_4
    end
    /* this is a comment
    insert into table_5
    */
    insert into table_6
    """

p = re.compile( r'^((?!--).)*\binsert\b\s+(?:into\s*)?.*', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
for m in re.finditer( p, lines ):
    line = lines[m.start(): m.end()].strip()

    starts_with_insert = re.findall('insert.*', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    print re.compile('insert\s+(?:into\s+)?', flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).split(' '.join(starts_with_insert))[1].split()[0]
```

Actual Result:

```
table_1
table_2
table_4
table_5
table_6
```

Expected Result: table_5 should not be returned since it's between /* and */

```
table_1
table_2
table_4
table_6
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Thanks for your solutions. Is it possible to use purely regex without stripping lines from original text?

I would like to display the line number where table name can be found from the original string.

Updated code below:

```
import re

lines = """begin insert into table_1 end
    begin insert table_2 end   
    select 1 --This is will not insert into table_3
    begin insert into
        table_4
    end
    /* this is a comment
    insert into table_5
    */
    insert into table_6
    """

p = re.compile( r'^((?!--).)*\binsert\b\s+(?:into\s*)?.*', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
for m in re.finditer( p, lines ):
    line = lines[m.start(): m.end()].strip()
    line_no = str(lines.count("\n", 0, m.end()) + 1).zfill(6)

    table_names = re.findall(r'(?:\binsert\s*(?:into\s*)?)(\S+)', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    print '[line number: ' + line_no + '] ' + '; '.join(table_names)
```

Tried using lookahead/lookbehind to exclude those between /* and */ but it's not producing my expected result.

Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot that both `--` and `/*` probably won't start comments when inside a string...

Comment: I think you should know about  `lookbehind assertion`

Answer (score 1):

In 2 steps with `re.sub()` and `re.findall()` functions:

```
# removing single line/multiline comments
stripped_lines = re.sub(r'/\*[\s\S]+\*/\s*|.*--.*(?=\binsert).*\n?', '', lines, re.S | re.I)

# extracting table names preceded by `insert` statement 
tbl_names = re.findall(r'(?:\binsert\s*(?:into\s*)?)(\S+)', stripped_lines, re.I)
print(tbl_names)
```

The output:

```
['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_4', 'table_6']
```

Comment: Hi Roman, your solution using findall is simpler than my original. Updated the code above with your solution. Is this possible to achieve the same result without stripping the original text?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import string

lines = """begin insert into table_1 end
    begin insert table_2 end
    select 1 --This is will not insert into table_3
    begin insert into
        table_4
    end
    /* this is a comment
    insert into table_5
    */
    insert into table_6
    """

# remove all /* */ and -- comments
comments = re.compile('/\*(?:.*\n)+.*\*/|--.*?\n', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
for comment in comments.findall(lines):
    lines = string.replace(lines, comment, '')

fullSet = re.compile('insert\s+(?:into\s+)*(\S+)', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
print fullSet.findall(lines)
```

gives

```
['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_4', 'table_6']
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin for your nice solution. This really works but would like to know if it's possible to directly use regex without removing lines? Updated question above. Thanks

Comment: Regex has no mechanism for deciphering context.  Removing comments completely, assures that you never find them.  As you might appreciate regex can degenerate in to an unreadable mess pretty quickly.  I'll further compress my answer.  I don't think you'll be able to get it without a removal step.  There are just too many what if scenarios.  I'll play around a bit more.